# 0 vs '0' with boolean operators

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

`0 == false` and `'0' == false` are both 'true'

However, `(true && 0)` is 'false', while `(true && '0')` is 'true'.

Why?

Comment: The operands of an equality comparison follow certain rules. With your first two examples, they are converted to numbers, and therefore equal. Using `&&` and `||`, the operands are tested for truthyness. The only falsey values are `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`. Hopefully this can help: http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3

Comment: idk about you but when I type `(true && 0)` into the console I get `0` and when I do `(true && '0')` I get `"0"`

Comment: @aug I think they were more or less being used in an `if` statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *abstract comparison* (`==`) rules are described in [ES5 11.9.3](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) while the rules for logical operators (`&&`) are described in [ES5 11.11](http://es5.github.io/#x11.11).

In short, `==` is just more complex than `&&`. Where `&&` just uses the internal `ToBoolean()` to evaluate its operands, `==` has various conditions that may result in the use of `ToBoolean()`, `ToNumber()`, and/or `ToPrimitive()`.

1. `(0 == false) == true`:

   > 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of comparison x == ToNumber(y)

   `ToNumber(false) === 0`, so `0 == 0`, so `true`.
2. `('0' == false) == true`:

   This also passes through step 7, resulting in `'0' == 0`.

   Then, starting over at the top, it reaching step 5:

   > 5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, 
   >           return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

   `ToNumber('0') === 0`, so again `0 == 0`, and again `true`.
3. `!!(true && 0) == false`

   `&&` simply returns the 1st operand if it's *falsy* (`ToBoolean(...) === false`), or the 2nd operand.

   It's strictly `(true && 0) === 0`.

   And, when used as an `if` condition, the result (`0`) will as well be [passed through `ToBoolean(...)`](http://es5.github.io/#x12.5) and `ToBoolean(0) === false`.
4. `!!(true && '0') == true`

   Again, this returns the 2nd operand, `'0'`.

   This time, however, `ToBoolean('0') === true` as `'0'` is a non-empty String, making it *truthy*.

Also, if you want simpler comparison rules, use *strict comparison* (`===`, [11.9.6](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6)).

Comment: `(true && '0') == true` is false actually (as `'0' != true`). If you want to emphasize the truthiness and the `ToBoolean` operation you'd better use `!!(true && '0')`

Answer (score -2):

'0' (or any non-empty string) is 'truthy' in JS. The == operator, however, does some strange type-coercion which is why many prominent JS figures including Crockford highly discourage it. This is a good example of why you should avoid it, it takes the string '0' and coerces it into a falsey value.

Here's a link that explains this process:

http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html

```
If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison 
    ToNumber(x) == y: false == 0 and true == 1 but true != 2
```

So even stranger than your example is this:

```
('1' == true) // true
('2' == true) // false!
```

Comment: Au contraire mon ami, it absolutely is related to == and its coercive effect. I never mentioned === so not sure where your comment is coming from.